# In Python, represent a SHA-256 hash using the fewest characters possible

Tags: python, hash, sha

What is the most dense way (fewest characters) that I can store a complete SHA-256 hash?

Comment: ...Why would you want to compress a sha256 hash? What's the point?

Comment: We are generating barcodes for our hash, and would like to keep them as short as possible.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be printable characters, then the densest set is... the exact way it comes out of the object if you don't ask for hex, base64, or another printable encoding.

Comment: You would have to say what the allowed character set is. The larger the character set, the fewer characters that will be needed. You can also consider truncating the hash to further reduce the size of the output.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `.digest()` on a `hashlib.sha256` object will return a 32-byte string -- the shortest possible way (with 8-bit bytes as the relevant unit) to store 256 bits of data which is effectively random for compressibility purposes.

Since 8 * 32 == 256, this provably has no wastage -- every bit is used.

Comment: Just a nitpick. If we're talking about *characters* (and not their encoding), like, abstract Unicode codepoints - then they could be denser than 8-bit. So, for texts e.g. printed on paper there can be a much denser encoding - e.g. with Emojis or CJK ideograms. But that's useless for e.g. barcodes, since barcodes encode binary data - and your answer is correct.

Comment: *nod*. Modified "8-bit characters" to "8-bit bytes" to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Charles' answer is absolutely correct. However, I'm assuming that you don't want with the shortest binary encoding of the SHA256 bash - the 32-octet string - and want something printable and somewhat human-readable.

**Note:** However, this *does not* exactly apply to barcodes. At least QR codes encode *binary* data, so just use `digest()` method of your hash - that would be the most efficient encoding you can use there. Your QR code generation library should most likely support generating codes for "raw" binary strings - check your library docs and find the correct method/invocation.

SHA hashes (and other hashes) don't produce or operate on *characters*, they work with binary data. SHA-256 produces 256 bits of data, commonly represented with 32 bytes. In particular, in Python 3 you should notice that `hashlib.sha256("...").digest()` returns `bytes` and not `str`.

There is a convenience method `hexdigest`, that produces hexadecimal (base16) string that represents those bytes. You can use base32, base58, base64, [baseEmoji](https://github.com/tsunaminoai/baseEmoji) or any other encoding that fits your requirements.

Basically, your problem is actually "I have a number and want a short encoding of it". Decide on how many distinct characters you can use (encoding base) and use that. There are many libraries on PyPI that could help. [python-baseconv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-baseconv) may come handy.